# 2 graphs in same line followed by same sequence in Android

Tags: android, graph, plot, achartengine, androidplot

I have data points offline in a file where i need to plot it in graph

I have tried AChartEngine, AndroidPlot but I needed in this sequence in the image below, How to achieveit, please suggest.[image]

Comment: In AChartEngine the repaint occurs with live data and shrinks it has no scrollview.

Comment: I have confidence to built in either of AChartengine or Androidplot but main doubt is without defining x or Y axis like this image above I wanted to plot the data currently even static will do. Need just guidance or a supportive links to do it.

Comment: I tried GraphView too. All are fancy and implementable but if we need a UI the best is to plot using OpenGL. Trying that, if there is any solution from you guys please share it will be helpful for me as well as developers who land here.

Comment: Is there any work around? if search led you here please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Chart Engine, created custom x & Y axis made 4 fragments and added the graphs to display. It is done.